# Solving $79=A\log_{10}(2B+C)$, $72=A\log_{10}(4B+C)$, $62=A\log_{10}(6B+C)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

For a question, I was given a set of $x$ and $y$ values to substitute into the equation $y=A\log_{10}(Bx+C)$ and solve for $A, B$, and $C$.

So I tried to type this into my calculator and solve for A, B, and C by using the x and y values I was given.

$$79=A\log(2B+C)\\72=A\log(4B+C)\\62=A\log(6B+C)$$

However, when I press execute to solve the equations in my calculator, it is continuously solving and never solves the problem.

Have I typed it incorrectly somewhere or something?

Comment: We can't see your calculator.

Comment: I showed you what I typed so there shouldn't be any problem right?

Comment: From the perspective you have entered the correct terms, and assuming your y and x values are right, the formula you have matches your input. It may be unsolvable?

Comment: The next few questions are based around the answer of this one, so I think it should be solvable. If it is unsolvable, then my teacher may have made a mistake typing up the question

Comment: The equality $$10^{79}=(2B+C)^A$$    tells you something?

Comment: What kind of calculator are you using?

Comment: Calculators evaluate numbers as soon as they know they can be evaluated unlike us. If we see 5*3/5, we would cancel the 5s, the calculator would evaluate 5*3 and then divide by 5. That's just an example not really how calculators work. The point is as @Piquito pointed, 10^79 is a huge number for calculators to calculate and it may even be possible that your calculator does not have enough memory to store this number for further calculations. Hence it's not continuously solving your problem, it's just taking some time.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui That explains why I get "Insufficient memory" sometimes. Thanks a ton for the clarification, makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 2):

From the initial system

$$2B+C=10^{79/A}=\alpha^{79}\\4B+C=10^{72/A}=\alpha^{72}\\6B+C=10^{62/A}=\alpha^{62}$$ where $\alpha:=10^{1/A}$.

We eliminate $B,C$ with

$$\alpha^{79}-2\alpha^{72}+\alpha^{62}=0$$ or

$$\alpha^{17}-2\alpha^{10}+1=0.$$

This polynomial equation has three real roots, among which $1$ and $-0.91160237164296303133\cdots$ which we reject, and $1.0433225893499999029\cdots$ which gives

$$A=54.2929119083438\cdots$$

$B$ and $C$ easily follow.